# Error Propagation through Iterated Functions (variable star data)

Tags: standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, convolution, error-propagation, astronomy

I'm an astronomer trying to smooth variable star data, and one way I'm doing this is using a 7-point, second-order Savitzky-Golay filter.  I iteratively apply the filter 51 times (i.e. I apply the filter, then apply the filter again to the result of the first application, etc.)  I've found that the equation the filter uses to modify the data for 7-point quadratic SG filter is:

$y_t = \frac{-2x_{t-3} + 3x_{t-2} + 6x_{t-1} + 7x_t + 6x_{t+1} + 3x_{t+2} - 2x_{t+3}}{21}\tag{1}$

Error propagating Equation 1 gives:

$\sigma_{y_t} = \frac{1}{21}\sqrt{4\sigma_{x_{t-3}}^2 + 9\sigma_{x_{t-2}}^2 + 36\sigma_{x_{t-1}}^2 + 49\sigma_{x_t}^2 + 36\sigma_{x_{t+1}}^2 + 9\sigma_{x_{t+2}}^2 + 4\sigma_{x_{t+3}}^2}\tag{2}$

However, I seem to be making some sort of mistake in doing this.  After iteratively applying this 51 times to my observational errors, it reduces the errors by *13 orders of magnitude*!  This is clearly absurd and isn't an error I can seriously report in my paper, but I can't figure out my error.  I had the same problem with my convolution method, the error of which I worked out to be:

$\sigma_{y_t} = \frac{1}{w}\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^w{\sigma_{x_i}^2}}\tag{3}$

where $w$ is the window size, for which I also used 7, giving an equation similar to Equation 2 without the coefficients in front of the errors.  This also reduced the error by about 13 orders of magnitude, and through guesswork, I discovered that:

$\sigma_{y_t} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{w}\sum_{i=0}^w{\sigma_{x_i}^2}}\tag{4}$

gave errors of the proper order of magnitude.  A similar method doesn't work for Equation 2, however. Since I don't understand *why* Equation 4 is right and Equation 3 is wrong (I taught error propagation to first-year physics undergrads as part of my GSA), I can neither discover the proper method to error propagate nor explain it in my dissertation.

I think the unknown factor is that I'm iterating the procedure (the 51 times I apply the filter), and I think that is altering the error propagation method somehow.  A Google search on 'error propagation for iterated functions' was unhelpful, and I wasn't able to find a similar question on any StackExchange.  Some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't hope for a crude approximation to remain any good after so many iterations.  You can compute iterated filters directly through convolution.  Indeed, that would be a much more efficient way to carry out your process, because you need to compute the coefficients only once and apply that filter just once, rather than filtering the series 51 times. You can further simplify this by noting that the result is going to be extremely well approximated by a Gaussian filter.

Comment: Would you mind sharing how the data looks like? SG may not be the right choice if it is producing crazy results. I have never heard of 51 iterations of SG on the same data set.  May be you can increase the polynomial order of even increase the number of odd points.

Comment: I wouldn't mind sharing it, as it's pretty publicly available anyway.  I'd like to clarify, though, that SG itself (Equation 1) isn't producing crazy results.  The 51 iterations (and actually, I think it's 50 upon further reflection) produces a nice, smooth curve.  What's producing crazy results is the *error propagation* through the SG filter (Equation 2).

Comment: @whuber I'm a bit confused.  Which part of my method is a crude approximation?

Comment: Formula (2) is the crude approximation.  It is *exceptionally* crude because it ignores the (very strong) serial correlations that emerge among the smoothed values after the first pass.

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that the errors change each in each iteration?  Because I always use the updated errors.  Or are you saying that the errors somehow become "entangled" with each other?  Because if that's true, that's *well* beyond my level of knowledge.  Statistics isn't my strong suit.  
  
Also, I use the convolution method you mention in your first post.  It certainly doesn't work in one step (I might be misunderstanding you), and it suffers from the same error issues (see Equations 3 and 4).

Comment: If it doesn't work, then you're not doing it right.  A perfect mathematical analogy is that you can compute the 51st power of a number with 50 multiplications or you can do it by taking a log, multiplying, and exponentiating.  It goes the same with convolutions.

Comment: I show how I calculate the error using convolution in Equation 4.  Equation 3 is what I worked out the error propagation to be for convolution, and that's what's not working.  It reduces the error about ~15 orders of magnitude.

Comment: @whuber I'm still having difficulty understanding the points you've made. One thing I've figured out is that I'm using a _recursive_ method, not an iterated one. That is, I'm using the output of the SG filter as the input of the next use of the SG filter. However, I haven't found anything on computing iterated filters through convolution. Could you clarify the terminology so that I can use it to search for more information? It may well solve my issue, but I need to understand it first.

Comment: You describe iteration (which is equivalent to *tail recursion*).  I am using standard terminology.  See, for instance, *Numerical Recipes.*

Comment: @whuber _Numerical Recipes_ was what I needed. I now understand how to do as you suggested: find the DFT of a vector of Eqn. 1's coefficients and multiply it by the DFT of what I'm filtering. To do _n_ iterations, I raise the coefficient vector to the power of _n_. Then I use the inverse DFT to get the filtered values. Turning back to error propagation, the first answer of [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28667/error-propagation-through-an-fft) implies that I do the same thing, but with the errors of the values instead of the values themselves. Is that correct?

Comment: It sounds correct -- but please note that one of the answers in the referenced question is useless and the other is wrong.